# Is systeminfo trusted enough to tell you the date of installation date?

Tags: windows-7

I have just bought a notebook and I found there is windows on it. it should be DOS, but it's common here the shop installing the pirated windows here. sorry for that ( i didnt ask for it, because I want installing linux on it). I tried with `systeminfo` and it gave me year 2009 and I saw the windows folder created at 2009 too.

so can I trust what systeminfo gave me, it was installed on 2009 ( I mean the last installation date)? or it's possible because the windows is not original and give me the wrong date?

I'm using windows 7 by the way.

Comment: On my win7 box, the Original Install Date is accurate, but my. %Windir% created date on is in 2009 which is definitely not accurate. I'm not seeing a "Last Install Date" in systeminfo

Answer (score 1):

When I run this on a computer I've reinstalled windows on multiple times and replaced every piece of hardware except CPU and motherboard, it comes up as the last install date.